# Error Error: Compile Error: Incompatible element type purchase_order__c for collection of Sales_Order__c at line 44 column 13

Tags: apex, trigger

i have phurchase order on that we have field Customer_PO, purchase order is related to purchase order line(Master detail relationship) where purchase order is parent and purchase order line is detail
now purchase order line is a lookup relationship to 'sales order line' which is child of 'sales order'
whenever user add  Customer_PO on purchase order it also add field of sales order.

And hear is code can anyone help me to run this code

```
trigger UpdateCustomerPOField on AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c (after insert) {

    list<id> pOrderLineId = new list<id>();
    list<id> sOrderId = new list<id>();
    List<AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order__c> salesOrderFieldToInsert = new List<AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order__c>();

    List<AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c> purchase = [SELECT Id,Customer_PO__c,(SELECT Id,Name FROM AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Lines__r ) FROM AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c LIMIT 1];

    map<id, AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c> purOrderLineIdpurOrderIdMap = new map<id, AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c>();

    for(AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c  purchaseOrder : purchase){
        for(AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Line__c purchaseOrderLine : purchaseOrder.AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Lines__r ) {
        pOrderLineId.add(purchaseOrderLine.Id);
        purOrderLineIdpurOrderIdMap.put(purchaseOrderLine.Id,purchaseOrder);
        }
    }

    list<AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order_Line__c> salesOrderLineList = [Select id, AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Line__c,AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order__c From AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order_Line__c Where AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Line__c In: pOrderLineId LIMIT 1];
    map<id, id> salesOrderLinePurOrderLineMap = new map<id, id>();
    map<id, list<AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order_Line__c>> salesOrderSalesOrderLineMap = new map<id, list<AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order_Line__c>>();

    for(AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order_Line__c salesOrderLine : salesOrderLineList){
     list<AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order_Line__c> tempList = salesOrderSalesOrderLineMap.get(salesOrderLine.AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order__c);
        sOrderId.add(salesOrderLine.AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order__c);
        salesOrderLinePurOrderLineMap.put(salesOrderLine.Id, salesOrderLine.AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Line__c);
        salesOrderSalesOrderLineMap.put(salesOrderLine.AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order__c,tempList);
    }

    list<AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order__c> salesOrderList = [Select id,Customer_PO__c,(SELECT Id,Name,AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order__c FROM AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order_Line__r)  From AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order__c Where Id In: sOrderId LIMIT 1];

    for(AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order__c salesOrder : salesOrderList){

        List<AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order_Line__c> SalesOrderLineId = salesOrderSalesOrderLineMap.get(salesOrder.Id);

        for(AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order_Line__c salesOrderLine : SalesOrderLineId){


            Id purOrderLineId = salesOrderLinePurOrderLineMap.get(salesOrderLine.Id);

            for(AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Line__c purOrderLine : purOrderLineId){

            AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c purOrder = purOrderLineIdpurOrderIdMap.get(purOrderLine.Id);
            purOrder.Customer_PO__c = salesOrder.Customer_PO__c;
            salesOrderFieldToInsert.add(purOrder);
            }
        }
    }

    if(salesOrderFieldToInsert.size()>0){
            update salesOrderFieldToInsert;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your adding a purchase order to the sales order list here

```
 salesOrderFieldToInsert.add(purOrder);
```

Since they are two different types it is not allowed

Comment: yes i do change it already but thanx..